# Laravel - How to remove white space in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have this Laravel-5.8 code

Request Rules

```
        'designation_name' => [
             'required', 
             'string',
             'min:5',
             'max:300',                            
        ],
```

Controller

```
public function store(StoreDesignationRequest $request)
{
    if (! Gate::allows('designation_create')) {
        return abort(401);
    }
    try {
            $designation = HrDesignation::create([
                'designation_name'      => $request->designation_name,
                'description'           => $request->description,
            ]);
            Session::flash('success', 'Designation is created successfully');
            return redirect()->route('hr.designations.index');
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
            Session::flash('danger', 'Designation creation failed!');
            return redirect()->route('hr.designations.index');
    }
}
```

View

```
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Designation<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
               <input  type="text" name="designation_name" placeholder="Enter designation here" class="form-control" value="{{old('designation_name')}}">
            </div>
          </div>
            
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Description</label>
               <input  type="text" name="description" placeholder="Enter description here" class="form-control" value="{{old('description')}}">
            </div>
          </div>                


       </div>
     </div>
    </div>          
    <!-- /.card-body -->
    <div class="card-footer">
            <button type="submit" id="submit_create" class="btn btn-primary">{{ trans('global.save') }}</button>
            <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='{{route('hr.designations.index')}}'" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
    </div>
```

The word length in the field is not up to 300, yet it's showing error that its more than 300

How do I trim

```
> designation_name
```

and also remove whitespace before submit or on submit?

Thank you.

Comment: You set a validation `max:300` max 300 character

Comment: 300 is characters, not words. If you want a word count, you'll need a custom validation rule. Beware, also, of multi-byte characters, like emoji. They can be misleading.

Answer (score 3):

Laravel >= 5.4 does input trimming by default on all incoming string fields on the request unless you list an exception input on `$except` array of `App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings` middleware class.

Just make sure that `\App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class` is included on your application's middleware stack by checking the `$middleware` property of your `App\Http\Kernel` class.

```php
namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        //...
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        //...
    ];

    //...
}
```

See [Input Trimming & Normalization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#input-trimming-and-normalization) on Laravel docs for more info.

Comment: I am using Laravel-5.8. TrimStrings is include and yet the error is there:          protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

Comment: @mikefolu so your input is longer than 300 chars and it's not about trimming. please post your sample input and the error you get.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that there is couple different whitespaces type:

1. If you want yo remove just a regular space character and make the the
   entire sentence as one a single word, the you can use `str_replace`.

   `str_replace(' ', '', $request->designation_name);`
2. If you want to remove all the white spaces including tab space then you can use `preg_replace`.
   `preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $request->designation_name);`
3. If you want to remove white space at the beginning and the end of the sentence or word the you can use `trim`

`trim('$request->designation_name);`